# Abrir una vista desde otra

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

En mi vista login.blade.php tengo:

```
    <div class="container" id="forgot">
        <a href="" id="text-forgot">RECUPERA TU CONTRASEÑA</a>
    </div>
```

¿cómo hago para que desde ese href abra mi otra vista mail.blade.php?

vi algo como {route::(vista)} pero no me funcionó.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma más sencilla y recomendada por laravel, asumiendo que sea una vista estática y la quieras llamar directamente (sin que haya procesamiento en el controlador o similar), sería definir una ruta directa a la vista, y asignarle un nombre:

```
Route::view('reiniciar-clave', 'email')->name('reset-password');
```

Sin embargo, si tienes una ruta que utiliza un método del controlador, la defines con su verbo correspondiente:

```
Route::get(...)->name('reset-password');
```

La documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing

Y para llamar a la ruta por su nombre (práctica recomendada en Laravel), usas el helper route:

```
<a href="{{ route('reset-password') }}" id="text-forgot">RECUPERA TU CONTRASEÑA</a>
```

Su documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#urls-for-named-routes

---

¿Por qué es una mala práctica utilizar el helper url() y se recomienda usar el nombre de la ruta?

Si algún día decides que la url no se llama `reiniciar-clave` sino `nueva-contrasena`, no tienes que buscar por todos los archivos de tu proyecto a cambiar dicho texto.

Comment: muchas gracias ! :D